# Custom CSS with Simple Form

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using Simple Form (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and finding it difficult to stylize radio inputs. I want to hide the standard input toggle and replace it with an image using the 'before' pseudo-elements for the 'label'. Because Simple Form publishes the 'input' **INSIDE** the 'label', I cannot reach it as a sibling using CSS. Since the input is now a child of the label. Typically label and input are siblings.

Markup:

```
<label class="boolean required" for="rfq_nda_accepted">
  <input class="boolean required" type="checkbox" value="1" name="rfq[nda_accepted]" id="rfq_nda_accepted">
  <abbr title="required">*</abbr> I agree to NDA
</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label
```

CSS does not support targeting parents. Also trying to avoid JS.  How do I use CSS to customize these inputs similar to this look: http://codepen.io/mitchmc/pen/pebIx

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't really know why you want it only on the label.  Here's how you can do it on the input itself:

```css
#NDA:checked {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#NDA:checked:before {
  visibility: visible;
  display:block;
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  content: "";
  background: url(https://placekitten.com/25/24) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<label class="wrap">
  <input id="NDA" type="radio" value="NDA" />I'm tired.
</label>
```

Comment: Trying to avoid any direct communication to a unique id (#NDA) because I want these input styles to be base (global) css changes. However, changing the input instead of the label is great! No idea why I was concentrating on the label. This is great help!

Comment: @user2963256 I only used an ID as an example.  There's no reason you can't just as easily change it from `#NDA` to `input[type="radio"]` lol glad it helped tho

Comment: And that's exactly what I did! :)

Comment: May need your help here Deryck. In Firefox a pseudo-element cannot overwrite the elements visibility. Therefore, an invisible element means its pseudo-elements (like :before) cannot overwrite with a visibility: visible :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the checkbox with CSS hope this is what you are looking for .

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
 display:none;
}

label::after {
  content:" ";
  display: block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
   color: #292321;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
  transition: background-color 0.4s linear;
}
label:active::after,label:focus::after {
 content:"";
 display:none;
}

label:active::before, label:focus::before  {
  content:" ";
  display: block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #292321;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #292321;
}
```

```html
<label class="boolean required" for="rfq_nda_accepted">
  <input class="boolean required" type="checkbox" value="1" name="rfq[nda_accepted]" id="rfq_nda_accepted">
<abbr title="required">*</abbr>  I agree to NDA
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post joyBlanks. The markup is dynamically generated, so I cannot that simply add a span or div inside the label. I am basically trying to figure out how to talk to the label based on the condition of the input (checked or not) using only CSS. Does that make sense?

Imagine you cannot change the markup and have to speak to it just using css. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, If you have access to any JS you can put a span. I will not say that piece is a nice work, but it will work in FF for now. This is just knowledge do not make a practical use for above snippet. Sorry

Comment: Totally appreciate your help joyBlanks!